# Avoiding Two Queries in Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

Recently, I asked a question about how can I retrieve docids of all terms (inverted index). Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061238/how-do-i-get-inverted-index-using-solrj)

Now using the query,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/terms?terms.fl=tags&terms.sort=index


    <response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">2</int>
</lst>
<lst name="terms">
<lst name="tags">
<int name="AbRam">2</int>
<int name="Amitabh">2</int>
<int name="Anjaam">2</int>
<int name="Aryan">2</int>
<int name="Baazigar">2</int>
<int name="Bachchan">2</int>
<int name="Barry">2</int>
<int name="Biography">2</int>
<int name="Bollywood">2</int>
<int name="Chakde">2</int>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

Now, to find out doc Ids of all these terms, I will be making a search using solrj to the solr-index. I am certainly sure I don't need to query two times, but could not find any other solution. Is it possible using Lucene library (I am trying to access solr index using Lucene to see if I can retrieve docids corresponding to all terms.) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about this, but I recently tried this also and don't believe this is possible with the terms component out of the box. For more info, follow [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) link.

It says it directly uses Lucene's TermEnum to iterate over the terms dictionary. I do think you could try to dig into the source code and construct an component that does what you want to accomplish(I've looked at your earlier posts also).

I've never dug into the source code of Solr myself but looking at some API pages, it should be fairly easy. Using [TermEnum](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/TermEnum.html) it's easy to gain access to all terms. And via these [Terms](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/Term.html) it should be fairly easy to acces the documents they belong to.(Note that this is purely hypothetical, I do not have any expierence with coding expansions in the Solr source code)